# Fb-login onlogin attribute breaks HTML5 validation

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, validation

Implementing Facebook login button with code given on Facebook's site ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button ) creates an invalid HTML5 code. Here's what http://validator.nu/ produced:

Error: Attribute onlogin not allowed on element div at this point.

What is the way to create a valid HTML5 for Facebook login button?